# Webclient calls to DownloadString cause my app to freeze

Tags: c#

```
string[] strArray = new WebClient().DownloadString("MYSITE").Split(new char[1]
                {
                    ','
                });
```

Whenever i use this code my app freezes till it gets the info, is there a way to stop that freeze?

Comment: You need to use async.

Comment: `DownloadStringTaskAsync` or `DownloadStringAsync`

Comment: It takes a while for the webclient to download that string, during that time the thread is not working on the GUI. No thread is, that's why it freezes up. The solution is to have a seperate thread doing the downloading while the original thread is keeping an eye on the GUI. async await is a very elegent way to do that.

Answer (score 4):

`DownloadString` is a blocking call. Control is returned only after response has been submitted. To make your UI responsive, use:
 `await DownloadStringTaskAsync` or
  use a thread from the `ThreadPool`.

In case you don't know how to use `async await`:

```
async void yourMethod()
{
   string html = await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(uri);
   if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(html))
      var htmlSplit = html.Split(',');
}
```

Comment: `DownloadStringAsync` isn't awaitable.

Comment: @l4V Weird but good to know.

Comment: But there is one awaitable. `DownloadStringTaskAsync`

Comment: That's the one. Confusing API.

Comment: It seems DownloadStringAsync spins a thread from the threadpool and you have to subscribe a callback. BS I say ;)

Comment: will i need any dll file?

Comment: @LewsTherin `DownloadStringAsync` isn't awaitable because it's a legacy async method, prior to the introduction of the async/await pattern in .NET 4.5. In cases where there was a legacy method, they used the convention TaskAsync.

Answer (score 1):

If you download something on the main thread, the app will stop to update the UI and your app will freeze untill it will finish to download.

You need to call `DownloadStringAsync`, so it will download it in another thread:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string[] strArray;
client.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, e) => 
{
  // do something with the results
  strArray = e.Result.Split(new char[1] { ',' });
};
client.DownloadStringAsync("MYSITE");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just create a thread:

```
Thread download = new Thread(DownloadString);
download.Start();

private void DownloadString()
{
    string[] strArray = new WebClient().DownloadString("MYSITE").Split(new char[1]
            {
                ','
            });
}
```

Comment: Why do you need threads when there are two async methods already?

Comment: Why to break your head when framework provided you Async?

Comment: Also... this isn't C# code...

Comment: Async methods do not take advantage of multiple cores/processors.

Comment: @Andrew: Why isn't it C#?

Comment: I'm guessing the use of `function` was due to laziness... some of us are guilty of it.

Comment: @LewisTherin: Oh, darn, sorry, I am in the middle a JavaScript file right now... just got mixed up.

Comment: @MingSlogar `Async methods do not take advantage of multiple cores/processors.` I would like to read about it. any link?

Comment: @MingSlogar: `function` isn't valid... Also, I disagree with your statement about multiple cores...  If I made my own `async` method, it would be up to me how I implemented it.  Normally it would just involve opening a new thread and calling delegates.  Which is "roughly" doing what you proposed.

Comment: @14V: The definition of async is that it runs when other code is not executing on the same thread.

Comment: I somewhat agree with Ming. async await by itself does not care about CPU cores or shiz. It is good for IO stuff so in that regards it doesn't give a crap. It could spin a new thread or it could use a task. It is implementation defined. However, what I know is it can free a thread to do other shiz until the IO work is done.

Comment: @14V: No, sorry, I just recall reading that in the VS2013 documentation.

Comment: Just for future readers not to get false impression [Multi-threaded Asynchronous Programming in C#... Getting started.](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/multithreadedasync05112007061031AM/multithreadedasync.aspx)

Comment: @14V: Very interesting article. I didn't know that.